# How do I redirect to a page with an ID that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Basically put, I have an action that saves a form to a database, then redirects the user to a list. From this list, the user can select a few actions.

One of these actions is essential and I would like the user to be passes directly to this straight after creating an object, however, as the ID of the first object does not exist yet, I am not sure how to pass the ID through.

For example Currently -

```
            //Excerpt  
            db.form.Add(ViewModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("List");
```

Then I have a list that is pulled in the normal way, and there is a link that the user can click to go to `/stage2/(id)`.

What I would ideally like is to change my code to something like:

```
            //Excerpt  
            db.form.Add(ViewModel);
            var newentry = db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Stage2", new {id = newentry));
```

I have seen that calling `SaveChanges()` in this manner results an int being returned, but, I have tried and it doesn't seem to pull the ID of the object, I have tried a few other things but am unsure of the syntax to use.

All I can think is to detach the object, then select it again and return, but, is there a more "slick" or direct way of doing this?

---

---

EDIT - I think I have worked this out... but, I need to wait 7 hours until I can post an answer.

Unless I am mistaken - in which case, please can someone tell me!... It looks like that Entity Framework automatically updates the object that you pass it.

When I pass it a `form` object, upon calling `SaveChanges`, it automatically sets the ID of the form object.

So, all I needed was:

```
        //Excerpt  
        db.form.Add(ViewModel);
        return RedirectToAction("Stage2", new {id = ViewModel.id));
```

Comment: You are correct, EF will populate the id once the object has been saved (via `SaveChanges()`) - although you're missing this in your "Excerpt" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken - in which case, please can someone tell me!... It looks like that Entity Framework automatically updates the object that you pass it.

When I pass it a form object, upon calling SaveChanges, it automatically sets the ID of the form object.

So, all I needed was:

```
    //Excerpt  
    db.form.Add(ViewModel);
    return RedirectToAction("Stage2", new {id = ViewModel.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
form ViewModel = new form();
// Add all your operations on the ViewModel object
db.AddToform(ViewModel);
db.SaveChanges();
//int id = ViewModel.id;
return RedirectToAction("Stage2", new {id = ViewModel.id));
```

After calling the "SaveChanges" method, your ViewModel id property gets updated

Comment: I don't really like this - whilst the application may not have many users right now, if there is any latency and/or lots of users in the future, I can see this causing problems/wrong records being retrieved.

Comment: I changed the answer, take a look and give it a try now